# Why does findViewById(...) return null?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

findViewById is returning null for me on an ImageView widget.  There is no error and nothing in logcat that indicates what is going on.  The id's match and other image views are being set properly.  Java and xml are linked by the class tag in xml pointing to the class defined in java which is a descendant of RelativeLayout.

I tried changing the name of R.id.more_icon1 and that didn't work.  Tried cleaning and that didn't work.  Used debugger to see that it really does just move on past and when it returns mMoreIcon == null.

What's wierd is that **the other ImageView's work just fine.**

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas?

Java Code: Class is a descendant of RelativeLayout

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    mText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    mIcon1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon1);
    mIcon2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon2);
    // mMoreIcon is the one that gets set as null. mIcon1 and mIcon2 work just fine.
    mMoreIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.more_icon1);

}
```

XML Code:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"
    style="@style/SuggestionIcon1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>

<!--     This is the icon that is being returned as null -->
<ImageView android:id="@+id/more_icon1"
    style="@style/MoreIcon2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon2"
    style="@style/SuggestionIcon2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/more_icon1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Silly question from my side, but have you tried recreating the R.java file (delete it from Eclipse, it will be recreated) or using a different name for the button? I once had the same sort of problem when using id's with numbers in them.

Comment: Not a silly question but yes I have.  I did a make clean on it which removes the R.java file and recreates all the generated files.  I also tried changing the name.  At first it was just more_icon.

Comment: Hmm. Now this is an odd one. I tried recreating your layout (Except for the layout being a descendant of RelativeLayout but that shouldn't be a problem) and it worked fine for me. 
I really have no clue what the problem might by. There's always trying to wipe your /bin folder and rebuilding the project. That solved several unexplainable problems for me before.

Comment: For me it was an issue of a bad reference earlier on, so I wasn't actually looking for the view under the right parent. Artifact of copy/pasted code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue and my problem was that findviewbyid only find child views. If the view is a sibling you'd have to call it from the parent. The activity should be able to find it.

Comment: I actually thought about this so I looked into it and it should be good as far as finding it.  The other ocons work so it should be finding them.

Answer (score 11):

I just recently had a similar problem when using the android:visibility="gone"

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutMenu" android:layout_above="@+id/layoutButtons">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_attachment" 
            android:src="@drawable/icon" 
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" /> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

With the ImageView above the TextViews, the application would crash at the following line.

Java file:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.display_image);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

If I moved the ImageView below the TextViews, the application would run but the TextViews were covered by the ImageView.

Once I removed the android:visibility="gone", the findViewById resolved correctly.  All I had to do was to set the visibility in the code afterwards.

```
textViewText.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. This was my code:

```
RelativeLayout ml = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_next);
```

After changing it to this it worked:

```
RelativeLayout ml;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_next);
ml = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

It seems that if you instantiate your layout before you setContentView() it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

View.findViewById might return null if the View's was declared gone inside the layout file (`android:visibility="gone`).

As pointed out by @danca, you need to call findViewById from it's Fragment or Activity.

Here is the code to safely retrieve the proper result of findViewById:

```
try {
    return findFragment<Fragment>().view?.findViewById(R.id.yourId)
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    Timber.e(e)

    (context as Activity?).let {
        if (it == null) {
            Timber.e("View can't be found!!")
        }

        return it?.findViewById(R.id.yourId)
    }
}
```